# Silverlight (Windows Phone) access textBlock

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to access textBlock from another xaml window?
I have the Main Page and there is the event handler xmppClient_OnMessage. I want to do something like this:

```
void xmppClient_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/message.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

            message.textBlock1.Text += e.Message.From + ": " + e.Message.Body;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the data using query parameters just like in html.

```
 this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/message.xaml?messageid=1", UriKind.Relative));
```

and retrive it like this on next page

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("messageid"))
    {
        //your code here
    }

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't - by the time you navigate to another window the previous one will probably be gone (aka removed from memory). You should pass all the data you need via Navigation as query parameters or just have a static object in memory.